# How to count the number of columns with a value on each row in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
IndividualID Trip1 Trip2 Trip3 Trip4 Trip5 Trip6 Trip7 Trip8 Trip9
200100001    23    1     2     4     4      1    5     5     5
200100002    21    1     12    3     1      55   7     7
200100003    12    3     3     6     3     
200100004    4   
200100005    6     5     3     9     3      5    6  
200100005    23    4     4     2     4      3    6     5
```

I'm trying to know the number of trips that each individual makes, so I would like to create a new column so the new table would probably look like this:

```
IndividualID Trip1  Trip2  Trip3  Trip4  Trip5  Trip6  Trip7  Trip8  Trip9 Chains
200100001     23     1      2      4      4      1     5       5     5      9
200100002     21     1      12     3      1      55    7       7            8
200100003     12     3      3      6      3                                 5
200100004     4                                                             1
200100005     6      5      3      9      3      5     6                    7
200100005     23     4      4      2      4      3     6       5            8
```

Are there any possible solutions? I would really appreciate if someone can help with it! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all the blank values to `NaN`, then count the `notnull` values by row using `sum(1)`:

```
df['Chains'] = df.iloc[:,1:].replace('',np.nan).notnull().sum(1)

>>> df
   IndividualID  Trip1  Trip2  Trip3  Trip4  Trip5  Trip6  Trip7  Trip8  \
0     200100001     23    1.0    2.0    4.0    4.0    1.0    5.0    5.0   
1     200100002     21    1.0   12.0    3.0    1.0   55.0    7.0    7.0   
2     200100003     12    3.0    3.0    6.0    3.0    NaN    NaN    NaN   
3     200100004      4    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
4     200100005      6    5.0    3.0    9.0    3.0    5.0    6.0    NaN   
5     200100005     23    4.0    4.0    2.0    4.0    3.0    6.0    5.0   

   Trip9  Chains  
0    5.0       9  
1    NaN       8  
2    NaN       5  
3    NaN       1  
4    NaN       7  
5    NaN       8
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `iloc` and `count`, which ignores `NaN` by default:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].count(1)

0    9
1    8
2    5
3    1
4    7
5    8
dtype: int64
```

If the values are *not* `NaN`, just replace the empty string with `NaN`:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].replace('', np.nan).count(1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using

```
df.ne('').sum(1)-1
Out[287]: 
0    9
1    8
2    5
3    1
4    7
5    8
dtype: int64
```

If it is NaN using `info`

```
df.iloc[:,1:].T.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 9 entries, Trip1 to Trip9
Data columns (total 6 columns):
0    9 non-null float64
1    8 non-null float64
2    5 non-null float64
3    1 non-null float64
4    7 non-null float64
5    8 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(6)
memory usage: 504.0+ bytes
```

Comment: @Dustin yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 3):

Simply look for the non-null items and then sum the rows:

```
df['Chains'] = df.notnull().sum(axis=1) - 1
```

I had to subtract one to account for your `IndividualID` column. This is the result I got:

```
   IndividualID  Trip1  Trip2  Trip3  Trip4  Trip5  Trip6  Trip7  Trip8  Trip9  Chains
0     200100001     23    1.0    2.0    4.0    4.0    1.0    5.0    5.0    5.0       9
1     200100002     21    1.0   12.0    3.0    1.0   55.0    7.0    7.0    NaN       8
2     200100003     12    3.0    3.0    6.0    3.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       5
3     200100004      4    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       1
4     200100005      6    5.0    3.0    9.0    3.0    5.0    6.0    NaN    NaN       7
5     200100005     23    4.0    4.0    2.0    4.0    3.0    6.0    5.0    NaN       8
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
>>> df.replace('',pd.np.nan).count(axis=1)-1
0    9
1    8
2    5
3    1
4    7
5    8
dtype: int64
```

Or if there `nan` do:

```
>>> df.count(axis=1)-1
0    9
1    8
2    5
3    1
4    7
5    8
dtype: int64
```

And just do:

```
df['Chains'] = ...
```

For assigning it to a column

Comment: That's pretty much the same as other answers, isn't it? :)

Comment: @RafaelC The only thing is i don't use `iloc`

Comment: Which actually makes your answer incorrect when used on his dataframe :S

Comment: @user3483203 Edited mine

Answer (score 2):

So long as we're giving alternatives, if values are `NaN`

```
df['cat'] = (~np.isnan(df.set_index('IndividualID').values)).sum(1)

IndividualID
200100001    9
200100002    8
200100003    5
200100004    1
200100005    7
200100005    8
```